# Unable to start SonarQube after migration from 6.0 -> 6.7 LTS

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to upgrade my SonarQube instance from a SonarQube 6.0 installation to  SonarQube 6.7.

When I start SonarQube, its failing with the following exception:

```
2017.11.21 05:22:43 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is already a quality profile with name 'Sonar way' for language 'java'
    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
    at org.sonar.api.server.profile.BuiltInQualityProfilesDefinition$Context.registerProfile(BuiltInQualityProfilesDefinition.java:78)
    at org.sonar.api.server.profile.BuiltInQualityProfilesDefinition$Context.access$300(BuiltInQualityProfilesDefinition.java:62)
    at org.sonar.api.server.profile.BuiltInQualityProfilesDefinition$NewBuiltInQualityProfileImpl.done(BuiltInQualityProfilesDefinition.java:170)
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.BuiltInQProfileDefinitionsBridge.define(BuiltInQProfileDefinitionsBridge.java:88)
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.BuiltInQProfileDefinitionsBridge.define(BuiltInQProfileDefinitionsBridge.java:67)
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.BuiltInQProfileRepositoryImpl.initialize(BuiltInQProfileRepositoryImpl.java:68)
    at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.BuiltInQProfileLoader.start(BuiltInQProfileLoader.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:90)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.access$001(PlatformLevelStartup.java:45)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:83)
    at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:80)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:196)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.access$400(Platform.java:46)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.lambda$doRun$1(Platform.java:121)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(Platform.java:371)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.doRun(Platform.java:121)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.run(Platform.java:355)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.11.21 05:22:43 INFO  web[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

I have not heavily edited the quality profile, so I'm comfortable with reverting that back to defaults.

Comment: I stumbled across the solution myself - I disabled the Java plugin, restarted and the re-enabled the Java plugin.

Comment: Great that you found a solution! If possible, please write it as an "answer" and mark it as "solution", so that it will be more visible (and you can earn more "reputation points" as well ;) )

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, it might be a problem of an outdated plugin. Here is what I did to solve the issue:

1. Remove the sonar-java plugin file from the extensions/plugins/ folder. (Also remove any plugins depending on java, if you see error messages for this in ce.log .)
2. If you are behind a proxy set up proxy settings for Marketplace in conf/sonar.properties . Note, that Marketplace does not claims for connection errors (at least in current version) just does not shows up available plugins. (But does log connection errors to web.log .)
3. Stop, and start SonarQube.
4. Login as Admin, and install the latest version of SonarJava plugin from Marketplace.